# How to calculate the data from table Dynamically

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate the data from the row using `TextWatcher` ,I have populated data from api this is my method to calculate this is my method :

**here I am entering the quantity and price is shown and want to calculate the total amount, by this method, I'm getting the total amount incorrect**

[image]

```
 for (Stocksdatamodel stocksdatamodel : stocksdatamodelArrayList) {
                            for (FinalMaterialModel finalMaterialModel : finalMaterialModelsArr
                                    ) {
                                if (Integer.parseInt(stocksdatamodel.getMaterialId()) == finalMaterialModel.getMaterialDetailsModel().getMaterialId()) {


                                    Grandtotal += Integer.parseInt(stocksdatamodel.getActualStock()) * Float.parseFloat(finalMaterialModel.getMaterialDetailsModel().getUnitCost());

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        totalamount.setText("Total Amount-"+Grandtotal+"");
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as your requirement...

```
EditText rateView1;
EditText qtyView1;
EditText totalView1; //May be TextVew

private String getTotal(String qty, String rate){
         double dQty,dRate,dTotal;
         dQty=Double.valueOf(qty);
         dRate=Double.valueOf(rate);
         dTotal=dQty*dRate;
       return String.valueOf(dTotal); 
//May return double by changing return type to double
}
```

Finally call this from onTextChange method

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(qty)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(rate)){
      totalView1.setText(getTotal(qty,rate));
 }
```